# Oracle Decompress String Compressed With Deflate Algorithm

Tags: oracle11g

In Oracle how can I decompress a base64 string which is compressed with deflate algorithm and stored in a VARCHAR2 field

My attempt to use UTL_COMPRESS.lz_uncompress is failing

```
select UTL_COMPRESS.lz_uncompress(src => 
(utl_encode.base64_decode(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('eJwLSS0uCS4pysxLBwAWHwQY'))))
from  dual;
```

Returns error

```
ORA-29294: A data error occurred during compression or uncompression.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_COMPRESS", line 29
```

The string does have crc32-checksum.